# How to find the implementation of a specific 'ioctl' call?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, libusb

Where can I find the file which includes the implementation of the following ioctl call:

```
ioctl(dpriv->fd, IOCTL_USBFS_SUBMITURB, urb);
#define IOCTL_USBFS_SUBMITURB _IOR('U', 10, struct usbfs_urb)
```

file descriptor is for a usb device.

Comment: Have you tried to grep the kernel sources with ioctl code (`IOCTL_USBFS_SUBMITURB`) or structure name (`usbfs_urb`)?

Comment: I found the answer. There is a header file containing the define line. The name of the file is "usbdevice_fs.h". This file includes the definition of the ioctl and the implementation can be found in linux usb core drivers "devio.c" -----> "/drivers/usb/core/devio.c"